# Hacking/Sniffing/recording GSM like Karsten Nohl

Tags: mobile, phone, gsm, sniffing

For a course at college, I wanted to reproduce the attack on GSM shown in this video by Karsten Nohl: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hjn-BP8nro.

From what I understand he used an USRP radio to record the data. Those devices all cost starting at 1000$. I was wondering what the requirements for a radio receiver are to do that hack and whether you can do it with a device costing 200$ or less. Wikipedia lists a bunch of software-defined radios and has a couple of devices in an affordable price range for a college student: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software-defined_radios

Obviously it should be able to run GNU Radio software and have a connection to the laptop with high enough bandwidth for transmitting all of the recorded data in real time, since the cheaper devices probably don't have an HDD/SSD (I assume USB 2.0 would be sufficient enough, but in the video posted above Karsten Nohl does not say, how many MB/s he recorded).

Now am I missing some other functions and requirements? What about the radio reception strength?

Comment: [gnuradio list a variety of forums](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki#III-Community-38-Communicating) and so-on that are probably a better source for this information.  I also recommend you check out raspberry pi or maybe arduino sites as those folks love to build stuff of exactly this sort.

Comment: Karstens devices are low powered and used only as a proof of concept. The main point being other less scrupulous actors will definitely use higher powered equipment.

Comment: Related answer using pytacle and Kraken here -- http://security.stackexchange.com/a/94901/140

Answer (score 1):

A great [link/thread](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2962/intercepting-gsm-communications-with-an-usrp-and-gnu-radio), with nice informations to start. USRP's are indeed quite expensive and RTL-SDR could be really cheap, but not always reliable.
I use the [HackRF-One](https://greatscottgadgets.com/hackrf/)(30MHz–6GHz, half-duplex though), and it costs 344€.

Comment: GSM interception requires two-way communication, so an RTL-SDR is out of the question.